# DB2 does not start

Tags: db2

I have installed DB2 Express-C 10.5 on my Debian 7 system, with this command:

```
./db2_install -f sysreq
```

The -f option was necessary because DB2 failed to get info about my system.

But now I cannot start my fresh DB2 installation:

```
root@this:/opt/ibm/db2/V10.5/adm# ./db2start
SQL10007N Message "-1390" could not be retrieved.  Reason code: "3".
```

Comment: Never execute DB2 commands as root; do that as the instance owner, which you would have defined during the installation.

Comment: ++ with mustaccio. Plus did you run ./db2iupdt to your instance afterwards? Sometimes that is needed to set correct permissions on files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `db2ilist` command will list the user account(s) where a DB2 server instance exists.  If no instances are listed, then you'll need to create one with the `db2icrt` command (after setting up a couple users and groups to accommodate it).

To start a DB2 instance, sign on or `su -` to the instance owner's account (db2inst1 by default) and run `db2start`.